# C: How to change my own program in my program in runtime?

Tags: c, self-reference, self-modifying

At runtime, either the assembler or machine code (which is it?) should be somewhere in RAM. Can I somehow get access to it, and read or even write to it?

This is just for educational purposes.

So, I just could compile this code. Am I really reading myself here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
    void *p = (void *)main;
    mprotect(p, 4098, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
    printf("Main: %p\n Content: %i", p, *(int *)(p+2));
    unsigned int size = 16;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%i ", *((int *)(p+i)) );
    }
}
```

Though, if I add

```
*(int*)p =4;
```

then it's a segmentation fault.

---

From the answers, I could construct the following code which modifies itself during runtime:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void * alignptr(void * ptr, uintptr_t alignment) {
    return (void *)((uintptr_t)ptr & ~(alignment - 1));
}

// pattern is a 0-terminated string
char* find(char *string, unsigned int stringLen, char *pattern) {
    unsigned int iString = 0;
    unsigned int iPattern;
    for (unsigned int iString = 0; iString < stringLen; ++iString) {
        for (iPattern = 0;
            pattern[iPattern] != 0
            && string[iString+iPattern] == pattern[iPattern];
            ++iPattern);
        if (pattern[iPattern] == 0) { return string+iString; }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    void *p = alignptr(main, 4096);
    int result = mprotect(p, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
    if (result == -1) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    // Correct a part of THIS program directly in RAM
    char programSubcode[12] = {'H','e','l','l','o',
                                ' ','W','o','r','l','t',0};
    char *programCode = (char *)main;
    char *helloWorlt = find(programCode, 1024, programSubcode);
    if (helloWorlt != NULL) {
        helloWorlt[10] = 'd';
    }   
    printf("Hello Worlt\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is amazing! Thank you all!

Comment: Machine code: Yes. Take a function pointer, cast to `unsigned char *`, read as much as you want (works on many common platforms). Writing, not so much.

Comment: If you are using windows OS then look for dll injection.

Comment: The machine code of a process sits in its virtual address space. The RAM is a resource managed by your OS kernel.

Comment: So the machine code is *not* somewhere in RAM (even if quite often it sits there). It is in the virtual address space of your process.

Comment: "Machine code" refers to the actual binary instruction code in memory, "assemby code" is a human readable representation of machine code.  An _assembler_ translates assembly code to machine code, by turning mnemonics into binary codes and resolving labels into binary addresses for example.  I answer this in a comment because it seems to be a secondary question - you should perhaps have posted a separate question, or just Googled it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch ; Even I am not clear what distinction you are making.  A virtual address maps to a physical address - the code being executed _is_ in RAM, regardless of the means of addressing it.  Of course it may be paged in and out of RAM, but it seems a somewhat academic point - if it is addressed, it will be swapped into RAM.  Furthermore, a system may not have an MMU, and the code could also be in ROM - but I guess the OP is referring to a modern Desktop computer and OS.

Comment: The machine code is in RAM when the processor is really executing it. But when a program is executed (by `execve` on Linux), that machine code is not (yet) in RAM

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : But the question is about self-modifying code - by definition the code is running an therefore in RAM (or at least addressable memory) at the time it is trying to modify itself.

Comment: The question don't mention self-modifying code and this is rarely done today.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it does. The question asks "Can I . . . write to it?" It might not be possible on a virtual or ROM machine but there are millions of processors out there, on which it  **is** possible.

Comment: Whether the code is self-modifying or is being modified from another process, the same issue arises - modifying code is not thread-safe.  With a single threaded app running on a single-cored system, code modification at runtime is merely a bodge, otherwise it's actively unsafe:(

Comment: You do not check the return value from `mprotect()` or `errno` if it fails.  That is to so , you don't know it worked.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : "_change my own program in my program_" - is that not self modifying?

Comment: Your `mprotect()` call fails, setting errno to EINVAL at https://onlinegdb.com/SkhjEAZuX

Comment: But what does "my program" means. I claim that a program generating a plugin and `dlopen`-ing is changing itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Machine code is loaded into memory. In theory you can read and write it just like any other part of memory your program as access to.

There can be some roadblocks to doing this in practice. Modern OSes try and limit the data sections of memory to read/write operations but no execution, and machine code sections of memory to read/execute but no writing. This is to try and limit potential security vulnerabilities that come with allowing executing what ever the program feels like putting into memory (like random stuff it might pull down from the Internet).

Linux provides the [mprotect](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) system call to allow some amount of customization for memory protection. Windows provides the [SetProcessDEPPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/WinBase/nf-winbase-setprocessdeppolicyQ) system call.

### Edit for updated question

It looks like you're trying this on Linux, and using `mprotect`. The code you posted is not checking the return value from `mprotect`, so you don't know if the call is succeeding or failing. Here is an updated version that checks the return value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void * alignptr(void * ptr, uintptr_t alignment)
{
    return (void *)((uintptr_t)ptr & ~(alignment - 1));
}

int main() {
    void *p = alignptr(main, 4096);
    int result = mprotect(p, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);

    if (result == -1) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    printf("Main: %p\n Content: %i", main, *(int *)(main+2));
    unsigned int size = 16;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        printf("%i ", *((int *)(main+i)) );
    }
}
```

Note the changes to the length parameter passed to `mprotect` and the function aligning the pointer to a system page boundary. You'll need to investigate on your specific system. My system has an alignment of 4096 bytes (determined by running `getconf PAGE_SIZE`) and after aligning the pointer and changing the length parameter to `mprotect` to the page size this works, and lets you write over your pointer to main.

As others have said, this is a bad way to dynamically load code. Dynamic libraries, or plugins, are the preferred method.

Comment: Yes, a process only has access to the virtual address space. I don't see why that abstraction needs to be addressed here. Sorry about that pun.

Comment: Because a process don't see directly RAM (except perhaps with `mlock`)

Comment: I never mentioned RAM, or said that you needed to have access to the physical address space. I'm failing to see how this abstraction is directly relevant to the question or my answer.

Comment: The OP mentioned (wrongly) RAM, and your answer did not correct that

Comment: I think you're splitting hairs here. The machine code is physically stored in RAM. Sure, the process doesn't have knowledge of the physical address and has to access everything through the virtual address space. But it's not wrong to say that your code and variables are "in RAM".

Comment: It is wrong. For example, when you have just started a fresh program with `execve`, most of its code is *not* inside the RAM (but the OS kernel fakes things to make you believe it is)

Comment: This works. You are amazing. Just updated my question with this.

Answer (score 6):

In principle it is possible, in practice your operating system will protect itself from your dangerous code!

Self-modifying code may have been regarded as a "neat-trick" in the days when computers had very tiny memories (in the 1950's).  It later (when it was no longer necessary) came to be regarded as bad practice - resulting in code that was hard to maintain and debug.

In more modern systems (at the end of the 20th Century) it became a behaviour indicative of viruses and malware.  As a consequence all modern desktop operating systems disallow modification of the code space of a program and also prevent execution of code injected into data space.  Modern systems with an MMU can mark memory regions as read-only, and not-executable for example.

The simpler question of how to obtain the address of the code space - that is simple. A function pointer value for example is generally the address of the function:

```
int main()
{
    printf( "Address of main() = %p\n", (void*)main ) ;
}
```

Note also that on a modern system this address will be a virtual rather then physical address.

Comment: This works. I'm on Linux, so can I still somehow start my program as root and mark the memory region writable. I just tried mprotect but it didn't work out (see my updated question).

Comment: @D.Rusin : I don't think the updated question changes the answer.

Comment: @D.Rusin : Changing your question to incorporate information from my answer makes this answer look slightly odd - bad form. It might have been better to  post a new question.  SO is not a discussion forum - it is not sequential narrative.

Answer (score 2):

On most operating systems (Linux, Windows, Android, MacOSX, etc...), a program don't execute (directly) in RAM but has its [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) and runs in it (stricto sensu, the code is not -always or necessarily- in RAM; you can have code which is not in RAM and which gets executed, after some page fault bring it *transparently* in RAM). The RAM is (directly) managed by the OS, but your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) only sees its virtual address space (initialized at [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) time and modified with [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), `munmap`, `mprotect`, [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html)...). Use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and try `cat /proc/$$/maps` in a Linux shell to understand more the virtual address space of your shell process. On Linux, you could query the virtual address space of your process by reading the `/proc/self/maps` file (sequentially, it is a textual pseudo-file).

Read [*Operating Systems: Thee Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to learn more about OSes.

---

In practice, if you want to augment the code inside your program (running on some common OS) you'll better use [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_(computing)) and the [dynamic loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) facilities. On Linux and POSIX systems you'll use [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) (which uses `mmap` etc...) then with [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) you'll obtain the (virtual) address of some new function and you could call it (by storing it in some function pointer of your C code).

***You don't really define what a program is***. I claim that a program is not only an executable, but also made of other resources (such as specific libraries, perhaps fonts or configuration files, etc...) and that is why when you *install* some program, quite often much more than the executable is moved or copied (look into what `make install` does for most free software programs even as simple as GNU [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/)). Therefore, a program (on Linux) which generates some C code (e.g. in some temporary file `/tmp/genecode.c`), compiles that C code into a plugin `/tmp/geneplug.so` (by running `gcc -Wall -O -fPIC /tmp/genecode.c -o /tmp/geneplug.so`), then `dlopen` that `/tmp/geneplug.so` plugin is *genuinely* modifying itself. And if you code in C exclusively that is a sane way of writing self-modifying programs.

Generally, your machine code sits in the [code segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_segment), and that code segment is read-only (and sometimes even execute-only; read about the [NX bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit)). If you really want to overwrite code (and not to extend it), you'll need to use facilities (perhaps [mprotect(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mprotect.2.html) on Linux) to change that permissions and enable rewriting inside the code segment.

Once some part of your code segment is writable, you could overwrite it.

Consider also some [JIT-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) libraries, such as [libgccjit](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/jit/) or [asmjit](https://github.com/asmjit/asmjit) (and others), to generate machine code in memory.

When you `execve` a new fresh executable, most of its code does not (yet) sit in RAM. But (from the point view of user code in the application) you can run it (and the kernel will transparently, but lazily, bring code pages into RAM, thru [demand paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging)). That is what I try to explain by saying that your program run in its virtual address space (not directly in RAM). An entire book is needed to explain that further.

For example, if you have a huge executable (for simplicity, assume it is statically linked) of one gigabyte. When you start that executable (with `execve`) the entire gigabyte is *not* brought into RAM. If your program exits quickly, most of the gigabyte have not been brought into RAM and stays on the disk. Even if your program runs for a long time, but never calls a huge routine of a hundred megabyte of code, that code part (the 100Mbyte of the never used routine) won't be in RAM.

---

BTW, stricto sensu, [self modifying code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-modifying_code) is rarely used these days (and current processors don't even handle that efficiently, e.g. because of caches and branch predictors). So in practice, you don't modify *exactly* your machine code (even if that would be possible).

And [malware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malware) don't have to *modify* the currently executed code. It could (and often does) inject *new* code in memory and jumps somehow to it (more precisely, call it thru some function pointer). So in general you don't *overwrite* existing "actively used" code, you create new code elsewhere and you call it or jump to it.

If you want to create new code elsewhere in C, plugin facilities (e.g. `dlopen` and `dlsym` on Linux), or JIT libraries, are more than enough.

Notice that the mention of "changing your program" or "writing code" is very ambiguous in your question.

You might just want to *extend* the code of your program (and then using plugin techniques, or JIT-compilation libraries, is relevant). Notice that some programs (e.g. [SBCL](http://sbcl.org/)) are able to generate machine code at every user interaction.

You could change the *existing* code of your program, but then you should explain what that exactly means (what does "code" mean for you *exactly* ? Is it only the currently executed machine instruction or is it the entire code segment of your program?). Do you think of self-modifying code, of generating new code, of [dynamic software updating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_software_updating)?

> Can I somehow get access to it, and read or even write to it?

Of course yes. You need to change protection in your virtual address space for your code (e.g. with `mprotect`) and then to write many bytes on some "old code" part. Why would you want to do that is a different story (and you have not explained why). I don't see any educational purposes in doing that -you are likely to crash your program quite quickly (unless you take a *lot* of precautions to write good enough machine code in memory).

I am a great fan of [metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) but I generally generate some *new* code and jump into it. On our current machines, I see no value in overwriting existing code. And (on Linux), my [manydl.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/manydl.c) program demonstrates that you could generate C code, compile, and dynamically link more than a million plugins (and `dlopen` all of them) in a single program. In practice, on current laptop or desktop computers, you can generate a lot of new code (before being concerned by limits). And C is fast enough (both in compilation time and in run time) that you could generate a thousands of C lines at every user interaction (so several times per second), compile and dynamically load it (I did that ten years ago in my defunct [GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/) project).

If you want to overwrite [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) files on disk (I see no value in doing that, it is much simpler to create *fresh* executables), you need to understand deeply their structure. For Linux, dive into the specifications of [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format).

---

In the edited question, you forgot to test against failure of `mprotect`. It is probably failing (because 4098 is not a power of 2 and a page multiple). So please at least code:

```
int c = mprotect(p, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
if (c) { perror("mprotect"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Even with the 4096 (instead of 4098) that `mprotect` is likely to fail with `EINVAL`, because `main` is probably not aligned to a 4K page. (Don't forget that your executable also contains [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) code).

BTW, for educational purposes, you should add the following code near the start of your `main`:

```
 char cmdbuf[80];
 snprintf (cmdbuf, sizeof(cmdbuf), "/bin/cat /proc/%d/maps", (int)getpid());
 fflush(NULL);
 if (system(cmdbuf)) 
   { fprintf(stderr, "failed to run %s\n", cmdbuf); exit(EXIT_FAILURE));
```

and you could add a similar code chunk near the end. You might replace the `snprintf` format string for `cmdbuf` with `"pmap %d"`.

Comment: Cool answer! Ok, so this seems difficult. But it's certainly possible to modify the program code on the hard disk. But it's in machine code. Do you know where I can read more about how that file is structured so I can modify it?

Comment: Why can't you simply use plugins? And what is your exact purpose?

Comment: As I said, just for educational purposes.

Comment: But that does not mean anything, and can be achieved and understood in very different ways. See my updated answer

Comment: @D.Rusin Under linux (and *BSD), the executable file format is ELF (extensible linker format) and there are utilities to examine/modify it (e.g. `readelf`, `objdump`) and there are libraries to process it, too (e.g. `libbfd`). Otherwise, use `dlopen` et. al. as Basile suggested. Otherwise, it gets complex very fast.

Comment: I'm not the DVer and this answer is [more than] good enough that it should not have been DVed. So, +1 from me to compensate

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward and practical way to accomplish this is to use function pointers. You can declare a pointer such as:

```
void (*contextual_proc)(void) = default_proc;
```

Then call it with the syntax `contextual_proc();`.  You can also assign a different function with the same signature to `contextual_proc`, say `contextual_proc = proc_that_logs;`, and any code that calls `contextual_proc()` will then (modulo thread-safety) call the new code instead.

This is a lot like self-modifying code in effect, but it is easier to understand, portable, and actually works on modern CPUs where executable memory is not writable and instructions are cached.

In C++, you would use subclasses for this; static dispatch will implement it the same way under the hood.