# How OS handles memory leaks

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, virtual-memory

I searched quite a lot for the question but was unable to find my exact query although it seems general enough that might have been asked and answered somewhere.

I wanted to know what happens after a process causes a memory leak and terminates. In my opinion it's not big deal because of virtual memory. After all physical pages can be still allocated to other/new process even if it was causing memory leak earlier (after old process caused memory leak)

But I also read somewhere that due to memory leaks you need to restart your system, and I dont seem to understand why???

Comment: You need to ask about a specific OS to get a better answer but in most modern OS a process' own memory stops existing when it is closed, so leaks there disappear.  Depending on the OS, shared memory and other resources like file handles or graphics objects might not be automatically recovered.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, so for mostly popular operating systems (say ubuntu distribution/windows) they would recover memory and memory leaks aren't dangerous ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended reading : [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

On common OSes (e.g. Linux, Windows, MacOSX, Android) each [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) has its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (and the heap memory, e.g. used for `malloc` or `mmap`, is inside that virtual address space), and when the process terminates, its *entire* virtual address space is destroyed.

So memory leaks don't survive the process itself.

There could be subtle corner cases (e.g. leaks on using [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) or [shmget(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shmget.2.html)).

Read (for Linux) [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), try `cat /proc/self/maps`, and see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238666/841108). Learn to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [Address Sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer).

Read also about [Garbage Collection](http://gchandbook.org/). It is quite relevant.

Comment: Thanks. Three easy pieces is also our course textbook! (Though i dont remember it talking about memory leaks). Thanks again :D

Comment: But it does explain virtual address space.

Comment: It is a very lovely book indeed!

Comment: So why would anyone be worried about a memory leak, if the OS just cleans up upon termination of the process anyways?

Answer (score 1):

In modern operating systems the address space is divided into a user space and an system space. The system space is the same for all processes.

When you kill a process, that destroys the user space for the process. If an application has a memory leak, killing the process remedies the leak.

However,the operating system can also allocate memory in the system space. When there is a memory leak in the operating system's allocation of system space memory, killing processes does not free it up.

That is the type of memory leak that forces you to reboot the system.

Comment: Why won't system space (which I assume is kernel space) address space not be freed? Could you explain a bit more or point me to a good reading?

Comment: Because it is shared by all processes. There is just one system space for the entire system.

Comment: But if only that process was using that system space addresses why not design smarter protocols to remove the physical mapping similar to what we did with user space addresses.

Comment: The operating system executes in interrupts and exceptions. Process ! might allocate buffer space (in the system space) and queue and I/O request to read to that buffer. Process 2 might handle the interrupt when the I/O completes so it needs access to the buffer. Memory in the system space is not tied to a process.